# Using custom objects with Pex testing framework

Tags: pex

I am trying to use Pex and Moles testing framework for testing my project.

I have small idea of using Pex for parametrized testing.

```
void SampleMethod(Employee emp)
{
/// Some business logic
}
void SampleMethod(List<Employee> emps)
{
/// Some business logic
}
```

How to do testing for these kind of methods?

Thanks
Ashwani

Answer (score 0):

Pex will generate a test for you and Moles will provide the stubs.

e.g.

```
[TestMethod]
[PexGeneratedBy(typeof(ProgramTest))]
public void someTest()
{
    SCustomer sCustomer = new SCustomer();
    int i;
    i = this.DoSomething((Customer)sCustomer);
    Assert.AreEqual<int>(0, i);
}
```

The "S" here denotes "Stub" and is a mock object of your dependent class, in your case "Employee" or "SEmployee". Moles does the stubbing based on the interface (IEmployee in your case).

You can then stub out behaviour using anonymous delegates:

```
customer.GetFirstName = () => "Charlie";
```

Does that help?